# phpexcel chart formatting lost after filtering

Tags: php, phpexcel

I created php code to output a line chart and associated data into an excel workbook. The x-axis are years and the y-axis are percentages. When I use the chart filter tool in excel to filter the categories which in my chart are years, the new filtered chart loses the year label and instead the x-axis displays a number, i.e. 2010 becomes 1, 2011 becomes 2, and so on. Also this seems to happen randomly after I apply the filtering criteria.
I would appreciate any help.
Thanks,
Bex

Comment: We can help, but it's **your** job to write the code. **[Put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** trying to fix the issue first, then ask **with a clear explanation** of what isn't working, how it should, add **[minimal, complete and verifable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Recommended read **[How to ask](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**, how to **[reward helpful answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234)**, and **[StackOverflow's Do and Don't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937)s**.

Comment: To improve the quality of your Question, please show us the code that you have been using.

Comment: I have a lot of code, I'm not sure which part to share. But I used this template  [link]( https://www.sitepoint.com/generate-excel-files-charts-phpexcel/) to create my  chart.